# Неправильно конвертируется дата через datetime в pandas

Tags: python

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D93XQ7VOpAk16a2OWUOOqxWyE7aYLOmp
Есть датасет с переходом на 2 даты января 2020 года, но эти даты неправильно конвертируются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Укажите правильный format для pd.to_datetime при конвертации колонки "Период", там используется формат даты по умолчанию, а он наверняка не такой, как вам нужно.
Там где вы пытаетесь конвертировать дату из колонки "Период" в index это уже поздно делать - дата уже сконвертирована из строки неправильным образом и преобразования в этом месте уже никакого не происходит и формат не учитывается, поскольку у вас в колонке "Период" уже дата, а не строка.
А вообще лучше указывать правильный формат колонок, а также колонки, которые нужно конвертировать в дату, уже сразу при чтении DataFrame из csv или при создании DataFrame из данных.
Когда вы конвертируете колонки на ходу и записываете их обратно с тем же именем это часто приводит к путанице - вы не знаете, какого формата у вас эти колонки, в разных местах кода они у вас имеют разный тип.